# Eclipse settings files in git repository

Tags: c, eclipse, build

Ok so we have a mono-repo that contains several C code projects. The projects are Makefile based but also have configurations so that they can be very easily built using Eclipse and VSCode. My problem is with Eclipse's settings files. There is  `.project` and `.cproject` files along with a `.settings` directory containing `language.settings.xml`, `org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.prefs`, `org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs`, and `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` files.

I personally use VSCode to build these projects but some users still use Eclipse and for some reason Eclipse automatically modifies some of the files, some of the time. I do not understand the content in the files and I am certain that the `.project` and `.cproject` are necessary for building.

I want the changes to these files to stop occurring in pull-requests. I'm open to any solution whether it be removing somefiles, changing Eclipse settings to stop modifying etc as long as after cloning the repo, the projects should still be buildable without any personal config. Anyone have any recommendations ?

Comment: use eclipse in CLI mode

Comment: @0___________ how does that address the question of keeping personal Eclipse configs out of git?

Comment: These files get only changed when the project settings are changed manually. So better find out why they are being changed and fix the cause (maybe an absolute path rather than a relative path or something else that people adjust to their needs of their local machine).

Comment: @Cubic These are not personal IDE settings.

Comment: *What kind of modifications is it making*? It doesn't rewrite files for fun. Can you include a diff of such a change?